# October CMS extend System/Models/File

Tags: laravel, extend, octobercms

I trying to keep original file name when using System/Models/File, I got following code to extend this model:

```
    namespace System\Models;
class NewFile extends File { public function fromPost($uploadedFile) { if ($uploadedFile === null) { return; }

  $this->file_name = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();
  $this->file_size = $uploadedFile->getClientSize();
  $this->content_type = $uploadedFile->getMimeType();
  $this->disk_name = $this->getDiskName();

  /*
   * getRealPath() can be empty for some environments (IIS)
   */
  $realPath = empty(trim($uploadedFile->getRealPath()))
      ? $uploadedFile->getPath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $uploadedFile->getFileName()
      : $uploadedFile->getRealPath();

  //$this->putFile($realPath, $this->disk_name);
  $this->putFile($realPath, $this->file_name);

  return $this;
```

It works with file itself, it keeps original name but problem is link to attached file is still being generated. Broke my mind but cant get this work. Can anyone elaborate how to fix it?

Comment: `but the problem is a link to an attached file is still being generated` means what do you need - stop generating links OR it's not generated properly?

Comment: I meant it still being generated by original October CMS method. For example, file path for uploaded image would be site.com/storage/app/uploads/public/5b3/74f/e7b/5b374fe7b9856296467891.png, but actually picture saved in site.com/storage/app/uploads/public/5b3/74f/e7b/logo.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I see it seems its try to use `disk_name` to generate URL

so you did well for saving an image

```
//$this->putFile($realPath, $this->disk_name);
$this->putFile($realPath, $this->file_name);
```

but you just need to replace one line .. just undo your changes and make this one change

```
 $this->file_name = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();
 $this->file_size = $uploadedFile->getClientSize();
 $this->content_type = $uploadedFile->getMimeType();
 // $this->disk_name = $this->getDiskName();  
 $this->disk_name = $this->file_name; 
 // use same file_name for disk ^ HERE
```

> Link logic ( **for referance only** ) `vendor\october\rain\src\Database\Attach\File.php` and `modules\system\models\File.php`

```
/**
 * Returns the public address to access the file.
 */
public function getPath()
{
    return $this->getPublicPath() . $this->getPartitionDirectory() . $this->disk_name;
}

/**
* Define the public address for the storage path.
*/
public function getPublicPath()
{
    $uploadsPath = Config::get('cms.storage.uploads.path', '/storage/app/uploads');

    if ($this->isPublic()) {
        $uploadsPath .= '/public';
    }
    else {
        $uploadsPath .= '/protected';
    }

    return Url::asset($uploadsPath) . '/';
}
```

Just make `disk_name` also same as `file_name` so when file saved on disk it will use `original name` and when the link is generated it also use `disk_name` which is original `file_name`

now your link and file name are synced and will be same always.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! But 1 more question, now October makes quite funny path to image /storage/app/uploads/public/log/o.p/ng/logo.png maybe is it possble to store files for example in /storage/app/uploads/public/ ?

Comment: hmm need to check it, will check and let you know

Comment: Hi, maybe you find some solution?

Comment: sorry i didnt get change to check it but i need to debug from core what is actual issue sorry but it will take little time as i am in kind of lot of work right now so :)